# python script running in php gives no output

Tags: php, python, curl, nginx

In a terminal running 'php file.php', the following script outputs text as expected.

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd("python /root/installer.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>

# php /usr/share/zabbix/rackspace/index.php
test
```

The file /root/installer.py contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'test'
```

But if I curl this page I get no output and no errors.

```
[root@http-1 ~]# curl fake.url.com 

[root@http-1 ~]#
```

My nginx configuration for this page is as follows:

```
server {
        listen       [::]:80;
        listen       80;
        server_name  fake.url.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/installer.log main;
        root   /usr/share/zabbix/url/;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        error_page  404              /404.html;
location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
                  }
       }
```

Can anyone assist me what what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure nginx's user have execute access to "/root/installer.py"

Comment: i have gone as far as to make /root/installer.py 777 but still nothing

Comment: Check nginx log for any err.